# Defining namespace in g++ works for some files but fails for others

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, undefined-reference

I won't be able to show any code, but let me explain what is happening:

I'm attempting to compile some software with g++; I have my Makefile setup. There is a main file which calls the necessary functions to get this software working. I have all of my dependencies includes, i.e. all of the header files, all of the .cpp sources, etc.

My problem is, several of the files require me to **define** a namespace called OPTLEVEL or else g++ errors out.

When I do this, for example: **-DOPTELEVEL=GENERIC**, those files then no longer error out since I now defined OPTLEVEL; however, several of the other .cpp files now error out because I defined OPTLEVEL. This is all a conundrum and I am not sure what to do.

Here is an example Makefile with how I'm compiling the source files separately; if I were to combine them together in one line with the Define, it would give me an error. This gives me undefined references as I explain below:

```
HEADERS_DEFINE_NEEDED = /Header/Needed/Path
HEADERS_NO_DEFINE = /Header/No/Define/Path
SOURCES_DEFINE_NEEDED = define1.cpp define2.cpp
SOURCES_NO_DEFINE = noDefine1.cpp noDefine2.cpp
DEFINITIONS = -DOPTLEVEL=GENERIC

all:
    g++ -c -I$(HEADERS_DEFINE_NEEDED) $(DEFINITIONS) $(SOURCES_DEFINE_NEEDED)
    g++ -c -I$(HEADERS_NO_DEFINE) $(SOURCES_NO_DEFINE)
    g++ *.o -o out
```

I have attempted to compile the .cpp files which require the define separately into their object files. Then I compiled the .cpp files which do not require the defines into their own separate object files, but linking them all together gives undefined references understandably.

The undefined references specifically appear due to the files needed the define now have their namespace looking like **GENERIC::FUNCTION_NAME** and the ones without the defines looking like **OPTLEVEL:FUNCTION_NAME**.

I'll take any sort of advice.

Let me know if this doesn't make sense, and I'll attempt to clarify.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is an example with what I'm looking at:
define1.cpp

```
#ifndef OPTLEVEL
#error "Did not define OPTLEVEL 
#endif

namespace OPTLEVEL {
    class SampleClass : public InheritedClass {
        <Code.....>
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but macro has nothing to namespace (at least without actual code which you could show). You are doing something so strange that for me this is [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is rationale to change namespace name by macro defined during build process?

Comment: This is software that I got and am attempting to compile it and integrate it into my own software; in their source code they have header guards that look like the following:
    #ifndef
    #error "Did not define OPTLEVEL
    #endif

Then in the other files they have the opposite. I understand what you are saying with this being an XY Problem, and I appreciate you pointing that out. This is a little more complicated than I would have liked.

Comment: Here's a question for you all: 
Is there a way when compiling to make a define for some of the source files, but to undefine it for others? I know that you can do -DOPTLEVEL=GENERIC *.cpp -UOPTLEVEL, but when I tried this it did not work. Any suggestions? If I get that working, it may solve my problem.

Comment: StackOverflow works best when you have taken the time to distill your issue down to a single concise question. If it needs code for clarity, then include minimal general-case code. Saying "I won't be able to show any code" detracts and is unhelpful. Likewise "I'll take any sort of advice" shows that you're casting around for others to solve your issue rather than asking a targeted question. Finally, StackOverflow is not a forum, so putting a fresh question in a comment is again not helpful — either search for an answer to that question or formulate it as a fresh question. Well-written question

Comment: Surely there is some specific purpose for some parts of the code to demand that a namespace be designated at compile time.  I have some guesses, but you should read the project documentation for information about that.  I strongly suspect that it is absolutely intentional that some parts demand that the macro to be externally defined (though not necessarily via command-line argument), and others demand that it *not* be defined.  I also think that for the former group of sources, `-DOPTLEVEL=GENERIC` is probably very wrong, even if the compiler accepts it.

Comment: It may even be that you are expected to choose one of those sets of files to use, instead of trying to use both sets together.  Again, read the docs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You may be right, and there is most likely a reason for it. I'm adding each of the source files one-by-one to see if I can get it to compile without the warning appearing. 

Thanks for all of the input everyone, I'll keep on trying.

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone I appreciate your input too, however, I had tried so many different things up to this point that I thought I would ask if anyone had any ideas. I could have definitely written my question better, for sure.

Comment: @JohnSmithV, I urge you to do as I recommended and consult the documentation.  Or if there is no relevant documentation, not even in source comments, then study the source to figure out what's going on.  Getting a successful compilation by trial and error is not a reliable sign that you have built the code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my original question was to compile the source files that needed OPTLEVEL defined into their own libraries. Then when it came to compiling the main.cpp file, I had to ensure I linked those .a's, and added the linking flags i.e. -llibName.

It took a lot of effort, but this is exactly what needs to be done.